# How can I match values on a matrix on python using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix

I'm trying to match values in a matrix on python using pandas dataframes. Maybe this is not the best way to express it.

Imagine you have the following dataset:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'stores':['','','','',''],'col1': ['x','price','','',1],'col2':['y','quantity','',1,''], 'col3':['z','',1,'',''] }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

```py
    stores   col1    col2    col3
0   NaN        x      y        z
1   NaN      price  quantity  NaN
2   NaN       NaN    Nan       1
3   NaN       NaN     1       NaN
4   NaN        1     NaN      NaN
```

I'm trying to get the following:

```py
    stores   col1    col2    col3
0   NaN        x      y        z
1   NaN      price  quantity  NaN
2    z        NaN    Nan       1
3    y        NaN     1       NaN
4    x         1     NaN      NaN
```

Any ideas how this might work? I've tried running loops on lists but I'm not quite sure how to do it.

This is what I have so far but it's just terrible (and obviously not working) and I am sure there is a much simpler way of doing this but I just can't get my head around it.

```py
stores = ['x','y','z']
for i in stores:
    for v in df.iloc[0,:]:
        if i==v :
            df['stores'] = i
```

It yields the following:

```py
  stores    col1    col2    col3
0   z        x        y       z
1   z       price   quantity NaN    
2   z       NaN      NaN      1
3   z       NaN       1      NaN
4   z        1       NaN     NaN
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please format a piece of code to have a usable dataframe. You need to share a reproducible code.

Comment: how are you getting the expected dataframe?

Comment: The question is : Why is line 2 getting z as stores value ... same for line 3 and y ... line 4 and x ? What is the rule you want to implement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can complete this task with a loop by doing the following. It loops through each column excluding the first where you want to write the data. Takes the index values where the value is 1 and writes the value from the first row to the column 'stores'.

Be careful where you might have 1's in multiple rows, in which case it will fill the stores column with the last column that had a 1 value.

```
for col in df.columns[1:]:
index_values = df[col][df[col]==1].index.tolist()
df.loc[index_values, 'stores'] = df[col][0]
```

Comment: thanks a lot. this really helped me and I could understand it very well.

Answer (score 0):

You can fill the whole column at once, like this:

```
df["stores"] = df[["col1", "col2", "col3"]].rename(columns=df.loc[0]).eq(1).idxmax(axis=1)
```

This first creates a version of the dataframe with the columns renamed "x", "y", and "z" after the values in the first row; then `idxmax(axis=1)` returns the column heading associated with the max value in each row (which is the True one).

However this adds an "x" in rows where none of the columns has a 1. If that is a problem you could do something like this:

```
df["NA"] = 1   # add a column of ones
df["stores"] = df[["col1", "col2", "col3", "NA"]].rename(columns=df.loc[0]).eq(1).idxmax(axis=1)
df["stores"].replace(1, np.NaN, inplace=True)   # replace the 1s with NaNs
```